# Get keyboard height or top position when keyboard open

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do I get keyboard height or top position when keyboard open? I found the following module but it's only for iOS. How do I get in Android?

react-native-keyboardevents

Answer (score 8):

You can access keyboard details through the keyboard events.

Format of data:

```
Object {
  "height": 282,
  "screenX": 0,
  "screenY": 401.4285583496094,
  "width": 411.4285583496094,
}
```

You can call access them thus:

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native'

keyboardDidShow (e) {
    const { height, screenX, screenY, width } = e.endCoordinates
    console.log(height)
}
```